# SystemVerilog: Why is interface not allowed in class?

Tags: system-verilog

Q. Interface is a static entity and classes are a dynamic entity. So interface can't be defined nor instantiated in class but Static functions can.

So if a static function is allowed why interface is not allowed in class because the interface is also static??

Answer (score 1):

An `interface`, much like a `module` is a collection of many things including variables, nets, processes, and connections (continuous assignments). That goes beyond what a `class` represents in SystemVerilog. If Verilog started out with classes from the beginning, we might not have needed interfaces, but that is all speculation.

Comment: interface, as well as a module and udp is a "design" element, according to the standard. As such, it must stand alone, defined and instantiated in a corresponding hierarchy of modules.